# run c program by java program on windows

Tags: c, windows

I have a Java program for the graphical user interface. This Java program runs a C program which is already compiled. I create a JAR file in order to make my program executable. As a consequence my C program is included in the JAR file.

I use those lines :

```
String[] Tab_arg =new String[6];

Tab_arg[0]="./src/generalisation.exe"; 
Tab_arg[1]=fileM.getAbsolutePath(); 
Tab_arg[2]=fileG.getAbsolutePath(); 
Tab_arg[3]=fichGA_absolutePath; 
Tab_arg[4]=fichGO_absolutePath; 
Tab_arg[5]=fileR.getAbsolutePath();

  try 
 {
    Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Tab_arg);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(inputLine);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The trouble is that the JAR file operates correctly on Ubuntu but not on Windows.

Comment: Well, did you compile the C program for Windows?

Comment: No, the C program is compiled on Ubuntu.
You mean, I should create another executable : one for Windows and this other for Ubuntu ?

Comment: Yes you should make 2 executables and check in the javacode which one to run. Windows and linux have a different executable format and different API's so there is no way the Ubuntu C program could run on Windows without proper emulation.

Comment: ok !
And, the way to run the Windows executable stills "./XXX" ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have compiled it for Windows, you could add the two versions (Linux and Windows) to the JAR file. In your code you could add this

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))
    Tab_arg[0]=".\src\generalisation.exe";
else
    Tab_arg[0]="./src/generalisation";
```

This should do the trick if the Linux version has no extension.